# Differentiating 1 from 1*1 or 1**1 in python

Tags: python

If I have a function that receives an argument and I want that argument to return True if I put a correct tab but return False if I put anything else, even if the result in one of the elements is one (like 1+1-1 or 1*1), how do I do it?

What can I do to return False if I put on the argument a tab with an element like 1*1 or 1-1. In this case "tab" can have elements equal to 1,-1 and 0 so 1-1 should return False. Here is the function:

```
#lets consider this for tab. as you can see tab is a tuple with 3 tuples, each with 3 elements
tab = ((1,-1,1),(0,-1,0),(-1,1,1))
tab2 = ((1,-1,1),(1-1,-1,0),(-1,1,1))

def eh_tabuleiro(tab):
if len(tab) != 3:  
    return False
else:  
    for row in tab:
        if len(row) != 3: 
            return False
        else: 
            for element in row:
                if element not in (-1, 0, 1):
                    return False
    return True
```

In this case if tab, eh_tabuleiro(tab) returns True (as it should) but eh_tabuleiro(tab2) also returns True and it should be False. What can I do?
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: ...but 1*1 is 1.

Comment: Indeed : you try to separate "a = 1"  from "a = 0 + 1". You just can't : the stored data in memory is just the SAME.

Comment: You should probably use strings instead of numbers to keep the "formulas" from being evaluated.

Comment: something like:    if str(element) != "1":